# PostgreSQL connection for IIS Server using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, npgsql

newB here. I'm creating a website using ASP.NET connecting to POSTGRESQL Database. It works fine in my localhost but when I deploy to IIS Server im getting an error: "The type or namespace name "Npsql" could not be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" is there I need to install to IIS?

Comment: Did you deploy all the necessary assemblies with your application? How did your deploy your application?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your NPSQL dll is available.